# .NET - is better to use async or thread for a function with CPU and IO operations?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, async-await

I have a class with a method that does a lot of IO. I need to launch this method a But it needs also to do CPU operations to check where to write data. It's better to use an async function or a new task in this case?

The code is below (VB.NET). The method is invoked for every "measurand", and measurands are ~3000. Data must be written on disk as soon as possible. Furthermore data arrives with a rate of 50 per second. Ideally when data of a measurand arrives, it should be written on disk without waiting for another measurand finishes to write its data.

```
Public Sub saveMeasurand(ByVal measurand_id As String)
    Dim meas_id As String = measurand_id
    Dim datum As SortedDictionary(Of DateTime, String)
    Dim save_meas_data As Boolean
    Dim first_meas_data As Boolean
    Dim first_ticks As Long
    Dim last_date_meas As DateTime
    Dim curr_date As DateTime
    Dim last_ticks As Long
    Dim curr_ticks As Long
    Dim datum_ticks As Long
    Dim row As String
    Dim meas_path As String

    datum = Me.data(meas_id)

    Try
        save_meas_data = Me.save_data(meas_id)
    Catch ex As KeyNotFoundException
        save_meas_data = True
    End Try

    If Not save_meas_data Then
        Throw New Exception(
            "Can't save data for id '" &
            meas_id &
            "', resource is locked"
        )
    End If

    If Me.dt = 0 Then

    End If

    Try
        Me.save_data(meas_id) = False

        Try
            first_meas_data = Me.first_data(meas_id)
        Catch ex As KeyNotFoundException
            first_meas_data = True
        End Try

        Dim datum_keys() As DateTime
        datum_keys = datum.Keys.ToArray()

        If datum_keys.Length < 1 Then
            Throw New Exception("No data to save")
        End If

        If first_meas_data Then
            first_ticks = datum_keys.First().Ticks
        Else
            first_ticks = Me.last_date(meas_id).Ticks + Me.dt
        End If

        last_date_meas = datum_keys.Last()
        last_ticks = last_date_meas.Ticks
        curr_ticks = first_ticks

        For Each datum_date As DateTime In datum_keys
            datum_ticks = datum_date.Ticks

            While datum_ticks - curr_ticks > Me.dt_tolerance
                curr_date = New DateTime(curr_ticks)
                row = Me.nanDatum(curr_date, meas_id)
                meas_path = Me.measurandPath(curr_date, meas_id)

                Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(meas_path)
                    writer.WriteLine(row)
                End Using

                curr_ticks += Me.dt
            End While

            row = datum(datum_date)
            meas_path = Me.measurandPath(datum_date, meas_id)

            Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(meas_path)
                writer.WriteLine(row)
            End Using

            Me.data(meas_id).Remove(datum_date)
            curr_ticks += Me.dt
        Next

        Me.first_data(meas_id) = False
        Me.last_date(meas_id) = last_date_meas
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' log me
    Finally
        Me.save_data(meas_id) = True
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not slow code.  Have you measured it?

Comment: The sub per-se is not slow, the problem is I need to launch it a lot of time. I updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

> have a class with a method that does a lot of IO

Then it's a IO bound operation and in such case you should consider using a `Asynchronous` method and best way to have one is using `async - await`.

You should generally choose to perform operation in separate background thread if the operation is CPU bound operation which is having to do with more calculation performed on CPU.

Comment: I 'm not sure I've understood. Do you mean that if the method does IO, even if it does also CPU calculations, it should use async-await, regardless of the time spent on IO vs CPU?

Comment: @MarcoSulla, When you say the method is IO bound; that means it does mostly IO then CPU processing and inc such case you should consider using async method (same for CPU bound work)